# Invalid Column name Gull

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8

I am using Sql Server with Netbeans. I am executing the update query using following code

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        //Connection establishment
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;databaseName=SQLConnection","Fateh","Fateh");
        //Statement Object
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        //For DML use executeUpdate method of Statement Class
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Emp"
                +"  VALUES("+2+",+Gull)");
        //Commit Statement
        con.commit();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message", "The Data is Entered", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And i am getting the following error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'Gull'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:865)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:687)
    at Employe.addBtnActionPerformed(Employe.java:117)
    at Employe.access$000(Employe.java:17)
    at Employe$1.actionPerformed(Employe.java:55)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Please help me.

Comment: You probably need `"VALUES("+2+","+Gull+")"`?

Comment: After executing this statement _st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Emp"
                    +"VALUES("+2+", Gull)");_ I got following error  *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Gull'*

Comment: What value do you intend to insert in the second column? Perhaps it is a string value you intend to insert? In any case, a tip: always specify the column names in your insert statement, e.g. `INSERT INTO some_table(first_column,second_column)VALUES(2,'some_text');`. Second, if you intend to insert the string "Gull" in the second column, surround the value with single quotes. Like so: `INSERT INTO Emp VALUES(2,'Gull')`, or in Java: `"INSERT INTO Emp VALUES("+2+",'Gull')"`.

Comment: Note, that if you intend to insert values like this, you run the risk of SQL Injection attacks. Research parametrized queries, and if you're comfortable with that, have the statement as a parametrized statement and supply the values as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Emp"
            +"  VALUES("+2+",+Gull)");
```

More precisely, the string concatenation is messed up:

```
"INSERT INTO Emp"+"NALUES("+2+",+Gull)"
```

will evaluate to such string: `INSERT INTO Emp VALUES(2,+Gull)`.

Since, it complains that `Gull` is invalid column name, there's no such column.

So my suspicion is that it's some variable, which value you want to paste there. On that occasion, you might want to try:

```
"INSERT INTO Emp" + "VALUES(" + 2 + "," + Gull + ")"
```

which will evaluate to:

```
INSERT INTO Emp VALUES(2,[whatever value Gull has])
```

But, keep in mind, if `Gull` is string, you must wrap it in quotes:

```
"INSERT INTO Emp" + "VALUES(" + 2 + ",'" + Gull + "')"
```

And last, but not least, you are prone to SQL injection! You might want to consider that as well.